# how to print the given pattern 1 2 3 3 4 5 4 5 6 7 so on

Tags: c++

I solved this pattern with one way but need another way to solve it.
I tried other ways but can't solved help me with your code.
pattern is given as:

```
1
2 3
3 4 5
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8 9 
....
```

what I did is

```
int i=1,j=1;

while(i<=n){
  c=i,j=1;
  while(j<=i){
    cout<<c;
    c++;
    j++;
  }
  cout<<"\n";
  i++;
}
```

Comment: *"but need another way to solve it"* What do you consider other way? for-loop, recursive, ... ?

Comment: Show fail attempts that we can fix?

Comment: Rather than using extra counters, you can just recognize the pattern that the inner loop always goes from `i` to `2*i`, so you don't even need an extra counter. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/dKo8P97fn -- or to make the loop even simpler, just run `j` from `0` to `i` and then output `i+j` (https://godbolt.org/z/5Tdx4a576). Using while-loops for this is excessive and unnecessary.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int n;
  std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
  std::cin >> n;
  int i = 1, j = 1;
  while (i <= n) {
    j = 1;
    while (j <= i) {
      cout << (i + j - 1);
      j++;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
got the solutionn hahaha that was so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to generate this pattern:

##### Approach-1

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int max_count{6};
    for(int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << j+i+1 << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

##### Approach-2

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int counter{1};
    int max_count{6};
    for(int i = 0; i < max_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << counter++ << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        counter -= i;
    }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
1 
2 3 
3 4 5 
4 5 6 7 
5 6 7 8 9 
6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: You don't need `counter`, `j` is enough.

Comment: guys how much is dsa important

Comment: @MohanRana [It is of paramount importance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm).

Comment: @MohanRana I've only seen the term _"dsa"_ used for this meaning by people with Indian usernames. It seems like it's a local term and the rest of the world doesn't know it.

Comment: @jabaa.. hmm.. In our computer science curriculum we have a subject named "Data Structure and Algorithms", in short we call it DSA :)-

Comment: @Aamir In our computer science curriculum, we had cryptography and DSA was one of the important algorithms. The subject was called "Algorithms and Data Structures", in short ADS. Using the name of a so important algorithm for something else would be really confusing.